# Finding the radical of $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I am taking a Lie algebras course as a prerequisite to study Lie groups. The idea of a radical of a Lie algebra (maximal solvable ideal) has been defined in class but no other statements or theorems are available.

I have a question that asks me to calculate the radical of $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, which is the general linear Lie algebra of $2 \times 2$ matrices with complex entries.

I just have no idea how to start the question; I know how to check something is an ideal of $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ but I have no idea how to check it's a maximal ideal, or how to check that it's maximal with respect to solvable Lie algebras.

I thought of just guessing a maximal ideal (from a list of common ideals, like $\mathfrak{u}(2,\mathbb{C})$ (upper triangular matrices)) and using the correspondence theorem to prove no bigger ideal exists, but I couldn't get anywhere with it.

Comment: The upper triangular matrices are a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, but not an ideal. (In fact $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ contains only two non-trivial ideals.) Try to find a solvable ideal $I$ and consider the quotient $\mathfrak{h} := \mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})/I$; if $J \supsetneq I$ is a bigger solvable ideal then $J/I \subseteq \mathfrak{h}$ is a non-zero solvable ideal, so the maximality of $I$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{rad}(\mathfrak{h}) = 0$, i.e. $\mathfrak{h}$ being semisimple. So try to find $I$ such that $\mathfrak{h}$ is already simple.

Comment: This has been discussed recently also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630749/computing-the-radical-of-mathfrakgl2-mathbbc-without-using-the-semisim). From there we see that $I=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Thank you, makes more sense now.